# Apache POI está separando as Runs no lugar errado

Tags: microsoft-word, apache-poi

Estou aprendendo a mexer no Apache POI para trabalhar com documentos docx e estou tentando fazer algumas verificações em um documento já existente:

```
XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open("conf/templates/relatorio_modelo_laudo/modelo_laudo.docx"));
this.nPag = doc.getProperties().getExtendedProperties().getUnderlyingProperties().getPages();

for (XWPFParagraph p : doc.getParagraphs()) {
    List<XWPFRun> runs = p.getRuns();

    if (runs != null) {
        for (XWPFRun r : runs) {
            String text = r.getText(0);

            if (text != null) {
                while (text.contains("<<")) {
                    String x = text.substring(text.indexOf("<<"), text.indexOf(">>") +2);
                    String result;

                    if (x.contains("{}")) {
                        result = this.getExpressao(x.substring(x.indexOf('{') +1, x.indexOf("}")));
                    } else {
                        String str = x.substring(x.indexOf("<<") +2, x.indexOf(">>"));
                        if (str.equals("nPag")) {
                            result = Integer.toString(nPag);
                        } else {
                            result = params.get(str).isNull() ? "UNDEFINED" : params.get(str).toString();
                        }
                    }

                    text = text.replace(x, result);
                    r.setText(text,0);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Esse seria o método que iria pegar o documento e lê-lo, o problema é que no documento eu coloquei alguns campos para ser substituído, por exemplo, "<< nPag >>". O sistema deveria ler, interpretar e substituir pela variável de mesmo nome, porém, por algum motivo a Run está cortando minha variável, que está no meio de um parágrafo, em 3 partes "**... *<<***" / "***nPag***" / "***>>* ...**". A minha variável está vindo em 3 runs diferentes.

> Este livro contém << nPag >> páginas, numeradas eletronicamente...

É assim que está no documento, mas essa é a única variável que está dando esse problema, talvez trocar o nome resolva, mas eu gostaria de saber o motivo... Se alguém já puder me explicar por qual motivo o comando na segunda linha não está me retornando corretamente o valor da página, eu agradeço (antes estava funcionando, atualizei o documento e começou a retornar somente 0).

Abraços.

Edit: Testei mudar o nome da variável e mesmo assim o erro persiste. Ainda não sei o porquê do POI se comportar dessa maneira somente com essa variável.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A maneira que eu resolvi isso foi juntar as runs em uma única run:

```
if (runs.size() > 1) {
    StringBuilder texto = new StringBuilder();

    do {
        texto.append(runs.get(0).getText(0));
        if (runs.size() == 1)
            break;
        p.removeRun(0);
    } while (runs.size() > 0);

    runs.get(0).setText(texto.toString(), 0);
}
```

Assim que eu pego a lista com as minhas runs, eu adiciono todas as runs para a variável texto até que sobre apenas uma run, depois eu só adiciono o valor de texto de volta para a run e pronto.

Answer (score 0):

Antes de jogar o erro no POI, você deveria tentar dar uma olhada na estrutura dos arquivos XML que compõe seu documento Word. Da mesma forma como eu fiquei surpreso ao descobrir que PowerPoint recorta em três blocos distintos algo como `{{marcador}}` (escolhi algo semelhante a Handlebars como marcação no meu projeto).

Como a manipulação de documentos Word ainda não foi muito desenvolvida no POI, você somente tem a possibilidade de recuperar o texto inteiro do seu parágrafo com `texto = p.getText()` mas ainda não pode substituir o texto do seu parágrafo com `p.setText(texto)` como no caso de um parágrafo do PowerPoint.

Eu recomendaria a remoção dos blocos de texto começando pelo último até conservar somente o primeiro. Assim eu teria reescrito sua solução como:

```
String texto = p.getText();
if (1 < runs.size()) {
    for (int i = runs.size() - 1; 0 < i; --i) {
        p.removeRun(i);
    }
    p.getRuns().get(0).setText(texto, 0);
}
```